# Is returning data fields on successful REST API POST/PUT/DELETE request an acceptable best practice?

Tags: ajax, api, rest

Just a general "best practices" question:

Say I've got an AJAX `PUT` request being made to a REST API in order to update a particular resource:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/loads/" + id,
    type: "PUT",
    data: {
        name: "some name",
        age: 34,
        title: "some title",
        company: "some company"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Is it acceptable practice to return any properties on this resources that have changed since the `PUT`, either directly (due to the `PUT`) or indirectly (because of other influences)?

For example, the `PUT` request could return:

```
{
    age: 37
}
```

due to other consumers/factors influencing this property.

Otherwise, should a secondary `GET` call be made after the `PUT` to retrieve the (potentially) fresh resource?

Comment: You should look at existing REST apis of mBaaS providers. Many typically send back the newly modified object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable, and perhaps even desirable. REST, after all, stands for Representational State Transfer, and so there is nothing wrong in showing the state of the affected entity/entities after a state-change has been effected. You also minimize chatter by not requiring a subsequent `GET` request.

You can also convey this if you have a semantic media-type defined for the result of this operation.

Comment: Great to hear; thanks! Out of curiosity, what exactly do you mean by "semantic media-type?"

Comment: A semantic media type is a media type that conveys information about the state-representation. It's exactly the way a browser works. For example, when a browser sees `text/html` or `image/jpeg` it knows the rules it has to follow to interpret that content. Similarly, you will convey those rules in the description of your custom media content (for example `application/json+person`). It is Level 3 of the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).